# Rails AJAX partial not rendering properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have:

```
<p id="click">Click here</p>
```

In contorller:

```
@details=Family.find_by(famid: params[:famid])
respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.json {render :json => @details}
end
```

and:

```
$('#click').on('click',function(){
 $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          data: 'famid='+id,
          dataType: "json",
          url: "/map",
          success: function(data){                
            document.getElementById('myModal').innerHTML = data.famid
          }
      });
}  

<div id="myModal"></div>
```

**This works fine. The `myModal` div tag is populated by the correct `famid` value**. But I just want to post the data to the controller via ajax and query the database and **use the `@details` variable instead.** So I tried:

```
$('#click').on('click',function(){
     $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              data: 'famid='+id,
              dataType: "json",   //do I need this? should it be html?
              url: "/map"  
          });
    }
```

Now I want to use the `@details` variable like:

```
<div id="#myModal"> <%= @details.famid %> </div>
```

How do I do that?

**UPDATE:**  Ok I did the following things and everything works fine (thanks to @Rich & @NitinJ) except the partial. It's not rendered properly.

**map.js.erb**

```
$("#myModal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@details))%>");
```

**_details.html.erb**

```
<h3><%= @details.famid %></h3>
```

**map.html.erb**

```
    <div id="myModal">
      <%= render @details %>
    </div>
```

**Update**:

Now the partial is rendered correctly in the browser console. I can see the `#myModal` div being populated correctly. But it's showing only in the browser console and not on `map.html.erb` page. What is wrong here?

Comment: Writing an answer to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ajax**

```
$('#click').on('click',function(){
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         data: {famid: id}, //you need to serialize your data
         dataType: "json",   //do I need this? should it be html?
         url: "/map"  
     });
}
```

AJAX is quite simple - it sends a request on your behalf. The [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function is from JQuery, so to get it right, you just need to pass the right arguments to it

---

**Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
post "map", to: "your_controller#map"
```

Because you're sending a `POST` request (rather than `GET`), you'll need a route to handle the request. And since you're sending to `/map`, you need to ensure you're going to catch that request & send to the right controller

---

**Controller**

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def map
   @details = Family.find_by(famid: params[:famid])
   respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.json {render :json => @details} 
   end
end
```

---

**Response**

Because you're dealing with JSON, I believe you'll be best handling the response in the view directly, like this:

```
$('#click').on('click',function(){
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         data: {famid: id}, //you need to serialize your data
         dataType: "json",   //do I need this? should it be html?
         url: "/map",
         success: function(data) {
             details = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
             $('#modal_body').html(details.famid);
         }
     });
}
```

To my knowledge, JSON is meant to pass data succinctly (with as few moving parts as possible), and consequently, we always handle the JSON response from the Ajax request; rather than a separate file

You can use the [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) function to handle this, creating an object you can then append to the page

---

**Update**

I believe your problem is you're using `JSON`

You can't load a rails `.js` file with JSON - you have to load `.json.erb`, or process in the front-end view. You may wish to change your request to standard JS:

```
#JS
$('#click').on('click',function(){
 $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: {famid: id},
          url: "/map"
      });
}  

 #Controller
 def map
    @details = Family.find_by(famid: params[:famid])
    respond_to do |format|
       format.js
       format.html
    end
 end

 #app/views/controller/map.js.erb
 $("#myModal").html("<%=j render(@details) %>");
```

Comment: I know this. I have done this. But I'm looking for an answer like @NitinJ as I have mentioned in the question. after the `data` has been posted and the query is made I want to access the `@details`variable from my controller. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Updated - if you try without JSON (I think Rails is just sending the JSON data; hence no error) You want it to load the `.js` template, and also make sure `@details` is an instance var, so you can access it

Comment: what should be the other partial? `_details.html.erb`, right? in the `#myModal p` tag?

Comment: Where are you calling `_details.html.erb`? You will have to call it from `map.js.erb` like this: `<%=j render partial: "details" %>`

Comment: Do I need to render `_details.html.erb` partial in `map.html.erb` also? inside the `#myModal p` tag?

Comment: You'll have to do all your rendering in the `.js.erb` file, and then you'll be able to use js to append the data you need to your page

Comment: I see in my server logs that only `map.html.erb` is rendered and no `map.js.erb`

Comment: Ok I think the error is something else. In the browser console I see the javascript source generated. there the partial is rendering correctly. all works fine. but in the actual page there is no content. `#myModal` tag is empty.

Comment: I would guess that means you're not appending the rendered partial properly!

Comment: what do u mean? I tried `$("#myModal").empty().append("<%=escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'details')) %>");`

Comment: Hey, sorry about the lack of reply - been sorting something out. Your comment is what I would do; have you tried it to see what happens?

Comment: Hey, do you agree to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21189403/2675010) (see the comments)?. Micha says one should create a different action for every ajax call. One should not make 10 different actions if he has 10 different types of ajax calls to make. what's your say on this?

Comment: The ajax call goes to any action you want. An action does that -- performs an action. If you want to do 10 different things, create 10 actions; if you want to do 1 thing, create 1 action :)

Comment: So I have a single page, say `index`, and need some ajax calls to be made in the page along with some normal queries (non-ajax ones), I should not write them in single `index` action? that feels like making lot of actions for ajax processes. :/ any alternative to this?

Comment: Noo you'd put them into their own action. I think you're getting confused with how Ajax works -- every request you create with Ajax is like a request in HTTP (I.E it doesn't matter *where* the request is sent - Rails doesn't care). This means you'd create individual actions for the specific Ajax calls you need to make

Comment: For example, we have controllers which have a `destroy_all` action (which is called by ajax). We created the route for this action, and now call it with Ajax whenever we need

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a js.erb template than render this template. Now you can access this variable in your *.js.erb template

```
alert("<%=@details.famid%>")
```

you can also update your text of p tag by

```
$("modal-body").text("<%=@details.famid%>")
```

Comment: that is what I'm aksing. :) Is the `POST` ajax query correct?

Comment: you do not need to define dataType: "json"

Comment: Let me know if you face any problem in that :)

Comment: made a `map.js.erb` template added `alert("<%=@details.famid%>")` to it and in `map.html.erb` in `p` tag with id `modal-body` added `<%= render @details %>` also added a `_details.html.erb` template. But nothing happens.

Comment: there was a `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` error. I removed the `map action` by protect_from_forgery :except => [:map]. there are no more erros.