# Rails AJAX error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have:

```
<p id="click">Click here</p>
```

In contorller:

```
def index
    @all=Person.all
    @person=Person.where(id: params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.js
    end
end
```

and:

```
$('#click').on('click',function(){
     $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              data: 'id='+id,    
              url: "/index"  
          });
    }
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$("#show").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@person))%>");
```

**_persons.html.erb**

```
<h3><%= @person.name %></h3>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
    <div id="show">
      <%= render @person %>
    </div>
```

**routes**

get '/index', to: "main#index"
put '/index', to: "main#index"

Now when I got to the index action I get

> Person not found with id = nil

Before even the page is loaded. Why is the @person instance variable executed directly? I'm not even able to get to the index page. How does rails ajax work? How does it know the **@person** variable is to be executed via ajax?

Comment: In your ajax call, where `is` id defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an Ajax error. It's a normal Rails error. You're doing:

```
@person=Person.where(id: params[:id])
```

But in the the index action there is no `params[:id]`, so what you're actually doing is:

```
@person = Person.where(id: nil)
```

That's what the error is about.

The main problem is that you're trying to do two things in one action. You should make a separate action for the Ajax call:

```
def index
  @all = Person.all
end

def ajax_call
  @person = Person.where(id: params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end

$('#click').on('click',function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: 'id='+id,    
    url: "/ajax_call"  
  });
}
```

Something like this. You'll need to add a route for the `ajax_call` action, but this is the idea.

Comment: I'm passing the id value from the ajax call. from the @all variable I get each person's id and that I'm passing from the ajax call.

Comment: @whoIsCraig you should try to debug the id variable on the JavaScript side, prior to the AJAX call with a `console.log('id', id)` or similar call.

Comment: @whoIsCraig, that's what you *want* to do, but it's not what you're doing. The main problem is that you're trying to do two things in one action. You should make a separate action for the Ajax call.

Comment: @kolrie, this has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: the id params has got a value. I just wanna ask if the @person variable is going to get it's value once the #click element is clicked (and never before that) then why is rails trying to get params[:id] when the index action is called? it's actually happening like that. I had this error before once so this time I ended up asking on SO.

Comment: When you load the page the first time it goes to `def index` and executes ALL the code in it. At that point you haven't clicked on "Click here" and there is no `params[:id]`. `params[:id]` will be `nil`. The problem is that you're trying to execute both the normal index action as well as the Ajax call from the same method. That's wrong. See updated answer for a suggestion.

Comment: @Mischa okay your updated answer will help. But do I need to make a separate action everytime if I have multiple ajax calls? Can't I do it in a single action? I can add a if condition like ` if params[:id]` right?

Comment: You could use an if condition, but I wouldn't recommend it. It makes your code harder to read. What do you mean by "multiple Ajax calls"? I assume one click on a button only executes one Ajax call, right? If different calls do different things they should have separate actions in my opinion.

Comment: @Mischa  okay. say if I have many sections in my index page. there are many different things I wanna do by ajax. so I need to make different action for each ajax call? is there a way to avoid this? Also, I have seen few code snippets online where people combine ajax and html, like I have done. is this a good practice? making a different action seems a lot of code tand putting everything for a single page in a single action seems right. what's your say on this?

Comment: **I think it's wrong to put it all in one gigantic method**. It makes it hard to read and you'll need a lot of if statements to prevent errors like above from happening. The rest of your code looks perfectly fine to me. The HTML that you're sending via Ajax is neatly put into a partial, so I don't think there's anything wrong with that.

Comment: okay. Thanks a lot for help. But wouldn't you appreciate avoiding too many methods for each ajax call? Is there any alternative method for this you know?